# keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\Users\USER_NAME\upload-keystore.jks (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: keytool, android-keystore, android-app-signing

```
[Storing c:\Users\USER_NAME\upload-keystore.jks] keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\Users\USER_NAME\upload-keystore.jks (The system cannot find the path specified) java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\Users\USER_NAME\upload-keystore.jks (The system cannot find the path specified) at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method) at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:293) at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:235) at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:123) at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1360) at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:415) at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:408)
```

---

Comment: maybe that path `c:\Users\USER_NAME\upload-keystore.jks` couldn't be found and you should add to your questions details about your caller so that someone may help you to understand why it happens?

Answer (score 7):

U Should change the path of the command

```
    keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\USER_NAME\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

default_path =c:\Users\USER_NAME\upload-keystore.jks

set your own valid path

```
     keytool -genkey -v -keystore D:\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

Comment: It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore
 ...\keystore.jks -destkeystore ...\keystore.jks -deststoretype pkcs12`